# strptime example for datetime with tz offset

Tags: python, strptime

I have the datetime string `2020-10-23T11:50:19+00:00`. I can parse it without the timezone as:

```
>>> datetime.strptime('2020-10-23T11:50:19', '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S')
datetime.datetime(2020, 10, 23, 11, 50, 19)
```

But I'm having trouble parsing it with the `00:00` version of the timezone. What would be the correct way to do that?

```
>>> datetime.strptime('2020-10-23T11:50:19+00:00', '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S+???')
```

Comment: For one thing, you've got the arguments reversed.  The format string goes second.

Comment: @JohnGordon sorry yes, I've updated the question.

Comment: @wim `%z` doesn't match that `tz` format. It will work on `+0000` but not `+00:00`.

Comment: I don't understand the votes to close this question as "needs details or clarity".  It seems clear what the OP is asking.

Comment: @wim -- I see, I'm using Linux / Python 3.6.9, so maybe there were some updates.

Comment: Indeed, looks like you've just barely missed that update in 3.7. You could pre-process strings to strip out that rightmost colon?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You're looking for %z:

```
>>> datetime.strptime('2020-10-23T11:50:19+00:00', '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z')
datetime.datetime(2020, 10, 23, 11, 50, 19, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc)
```

Beware of some Python version compatibility notes:

> *Changed in version 3.7:* When the `%z` directive is provided to the `strptime()` method, the UTC offsets can have a colon as a separator between hours, minutes and seconds. For example, `'+01:00:00'` will be parsed as an offset of one hour. In addition, providing `'Z'` is identical to `'+00:00'`.

More robust approach, it's not `strptime`, but it's still in stdlib since Python 3.7:

```
>>> datetime.fromisoformat('2020-10-23T11:50:19+00:00')
datetime.datetime(2020, 10, 23, 11, 50, 19, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc)
```

As [documented](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.fromisoformat) this function supports strings in the format:

```
YYYY-MM-DD[*HH[:MM[:SS[.fff[fff]]]][+HH:MM[:SS[.ffffff]]]]
```

where * can match any single character (not just a T).

Answer (score 2):

The `dateutil.parser` function will parse that timezone format:

```
from dateutil.parser import parse

dt = parse('2020-10-23T11:50:19+00:00')
print(dt.date())
print(dt.time())
print(dt.tzinfo)
```

Result:

```
2020-10-23
11:50:19
tzutc()
```

You can combine the separate `date`, `time` and `tzinfo` objects into a `datetime`, if that's what you need, like this:

```
dt = datetime.combine(dt.date(), dt.time(), tzinfo=dt.tzinfo)
print(dt)
```

Result:

```
2020-10-23 11:50:19+00:00
```